# Array will not replace value at index

Tags: javascript

I can not replace value of object in the array :

```
var uploadedProductPhotos=[]; //global
```

later I am copying another array to this array with :

```
uploadedProductPhotos=input.files;
```

and print it to check that **indeed** i get the right 3 files inside the array.
Then I try to replace the first element:

```
uploadedProductPhotos[0]=input.files[0];
console.log(uploadedProductPhotos[0]);
console.log(input.files[0]);
console.log(uploadedProductPhotos);
```

First 2 logs will show the previous file and the new file 
(`input.files[0]`), but the last log will show the original array so first element stay the same and not being replace with what printed in `console.log(input.files[0]);`

Comment: You are replacing it with same element. `uploadedProductPhotos[0]` and `input.files[0]` are same as you assign it `uploadedProductPhotos=input.files;`. And also you are not copying the array. Try using `uploadedProductPhotos=[...input.files]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously didn't really copy the array in the first place.
Solved by adding every element individually to the array :

```
uploadedProductPhotos.push(input.files[k]);
```

Or can be solved by copying array with `slice` function .

Answer (score 0):

instead of individually pushing the elements , you can try using the es6 semantics.

```
uploadedProductPhotos=[...input.files]
```

it pushed the all the files to the var `uploadedProductPhotos`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options how to replace an item on an index:
- use push function,
- use slice function (with correct arguments),
- use rest argument for new value